# I had to run modprobe wl after every boot

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, modprobe

Wireless will not working unless I run:

```
sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe wl
```

In terminal, how to prevent that?

The current workaround I have is adding `modprobe` command to `/etc/rc.local`, but is there a way of making it work without having to run `modprobe` on every boot ?

Comment: iirc modprobe has a config file in /etc where you can define which modules to insert at boot time. Did you check that?  From your command I'm guessing that it's supposed to be already inserted but it's not working , is that so ?

Comment: I've found `/etc/modprobe.d` on etc directory, what should I do next ?

Comment: No , that's  the right directory. I found it. Automatic  module insertion should be done via `/etc/modules` . That's one piece of the puzzle, but what we need to know is whether or not your module is inserted at boot time already. Once you boot, run `lsmod | grep '^wl'` command and see if finds anything. If it doesn't that means your  module isn't inserted at  boot. Then it's simple - just add  `wl` on a line by itself to `/etc/modules`. Otherwise, there's something else going on.